# Add every n items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I have an array like so:

```
[5, 12, 43, 65, 34 ...]
```

Just a normal array of numbers.
What I wan't to do is write a function `group(n, arr)` which adds every n numbers in the array.

For example if I call `group(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])` it should return

```
[
 3 //1+2,
 7 //3+4,
 11 //5+6,
 15 //7+8,
 19 //9+10,
 11 //whatever remains
]
```

I haven't tried anything yet, I will soon update with what I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
function group(n, arr) {
  // initialize array to be returned
  let res = [];
  // validate n
  if(n > 0 && n <= arr.length) {
    // iterate over arr while updating acc
    res = arr.reduce((acc, num, index) => {
      // if the current index has no remainder with n, add a new number
      if(index%n === 0) acc.push(num);
      // else update the last added number to the array
      else acc[acc.length-1] += num;
      // return acc in each iteration
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
  return res;
}

console.log( group(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]) );
```

Comment: Thank you! In fact, I never heard of such a function.

Comment: This is a 'code only' answer. It would be nice if you could explain to the OP why this helps solve the original problem.  Also, you shouldn't answer questions where the OP has made no effort to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @SiddharthShyniben you are welcome, you can do this using other types of loops as well, focus on the logic to find the solution

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer good comment, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

This approach features two loops, one for checking the outer index and anoter for iterating the wanted count of items for summing.

```js
function group(n, array) {
    const result = [];
    let i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < n && i + j < array.length; j++) {
            sum += array[i + j];        
        }
        result.push(sum);
        i += n;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(group(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.from` to create the result array and then use its mapper to make the sums. These sums can be made by using `reduce` on the relevant slice of the array .

This is a *functional programming* solution:

```js
const group = (step, arr) =>
    Array.from({length: Math.ceil(arr.length/step)}, (_, i) =>
        arr.slice(i*step, (i+1)*step).reduce((a, b) => a+b)
    );

console.log(group(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]));
```